# Laravel SHOW WARNINGS gives unbuffered queries active error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to run:

```
DB::select('SHOW WARNINGS');
```

Once I have executed an update statement for a MySQL database, however whenever this one specific line runs I get the exception:

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOSt
  atement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by
   setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. (SQL: SHOW WARNINGS)
```

I tried running the statement at the start of the method so there are no other buffers running at all however the same error occurs? I read that this can sometimes be due to a syntax error and nothing to do at all with other buffer queries being active however I cannot see anything wrong with this query..? Any other query I make runs fine, just this one runs into issues...

May I also add:

I want to avoid setting MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true

I have also tried running this query on another project and get the exact same error...